# how to fix "celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'cefla.add'" bug?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I run curl -i http://my_ip_address:5000/lzh_tw/api/v1.0/test on my client computer, it will cause "celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'cefla.add' ".

However, if I run it again, it will return '9' normally. If I run it again, it will cause an the same exception. One exception followed by one correct return. I don't know the reason behind it.

```py
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'pyamqp://guest@localhost//'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'rpc://guest@localhost//'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@app.route('/lzh_tw/api/v1.0/test', methods=['GET'])
def test_func():
    res = add.delay(4,5)
    while not res.ready():
        pass
    data = res.get()
    return str(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Comment: Could you provide the command how you start celery worker?

Comment: @stasiekz I knew the reason. I forgot to stop a worker I started before, and that worker don't have the function 'celery.add'. So when the request is sent the previous worker, it causes exception. When the new work receive the request, it gives the correct result.